# How we can get a div with HTML data in a JavaScript variable

Tags: php

```
<div id='myid'>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>A</strong></li>
            <li><strong>B</strong></li>
            <li><strong>C</strong></li>
            <li><strong>D</strong></li>
            <li><strong>E</strong></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get a div with HTML data in a JavaScript variable?

Comment: What do you want to store ?, html code or the text ?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question ... You can get the HTML content of an element with something like that :

var content = document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML ;

Comment: @vijay rathore can you mark the answer as solved pls if the problem is solved pls sir ? :)

Comment: no its not solved i want to get the data of a div from website and want to store in a php variable. we can do this in js by getelementbyid.innerhtml but i want to do this in php

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, if you want to store the html :

```
var html = $('#myid').html();
```

if you want to store the text only  :

```
var html = $('#myid').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use php right ?

If it's the case you will have to use the DOMElement class http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

In your case:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTMLFile('YOUR HTML FILE PATH');    
$elem = $doc->getElementById('myid'); 

// loop through all childNodes, getting html        
$children = $elem->childNodes; 
foreach ($children as $child) { 
    $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));        
    $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML(); 
} 

die(var_dump($innerHTML));
```